# i want to use directive in popover, using angular-strap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using Angular-Strap.
I want to use directive in the content of  a popover.
this is the relevant code from Angular-Strap (bs-popover):

```
popover.getPosition = function () {
  var r = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.getPosition.apply(this, arguments);
  $compile(this.$tip)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
  this.$tip.data('popover', this);
  return r;
};
```

The problem is that in the first time the popover positioning is calculate differently from the other times.
After debugging i noticed that the first time the popover supposed to show the content is not compiled, it seem the the compile function has async procedure in it.
the tooltip is saved(like cache) so the next time the popover is calculate the content is already compiled and i am getting the correct results.